# Is there a way to do an INSERT or SELECT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I see that there is a INSERT ON UPDATE which inserts a new row if the primary key does not exist or update the other attributes if there is an entry with that primary key. Is there one that does INSERT or SELECT, inserts the record based on primary key, but if there is a row with that primary key already, select the row.

Comment: Not in a single statement, no.  But within your application code you can `INSERT` and, if it fails due to a key collision, then `SELECT`.

Comment: Or alternatively, `SELECT`, and if no row is returned, try the `INSERT` (but still catch the possible key collision because some other session may have inserted the value in the brief moment between your `SELECT` and `INSERT`).

Comment: The logic behind the function doing what you want if it existed would be crooked and irrelevant.

Comment: Can someone write your comment as an answer so I can close this one.

Comment: @Sebas, can you elaborate? I am trying to find an analog to find_or_initialize_by that exists in ActiveRecord's Ruby ORM.

Comment: Hi @denniss. Unless you are in a specific situation, which justifies virtually any kind of implementation, doing an insert or a select in one function is inconsistent. That's the definition of a *function*: it bears a simple technical functionality. Inserting is different than selecting, fundamentally (inserting or replacing is way closer, for example). This belongs to coding religion, I don't think it has any strong valid technical argument behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the other commenters have stated, this is probably better suited to application logic instead of an SQL statement. There is no built-in MySQL SQL syntax that can accomplish what you ask.

But you can make your own [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-views.html) to accomplish the same thing, awkward as it may be.